# How to prevent .htaccess rewriting?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, spam

I am currently managing several of my own sites. Their htaccess files are repeatedly being overwritten to redirect users coming from google searches etc to russian spam sites. I have changed all my passwords, tried every conceivable combination of permissions and contacted my hosting supported and still have no solution. The only way to remove it is to manually rewrite the htaccess to its normal state, which I do, but the malicious conditions are just put in again.

My questions:

Is there any foolproof way to prevent this? I know that the thumb.php used in wordpress had a bug to allow people to do this, but my install of wordpress has no theme or plugin with thumb.php in any form.

In case there is no solution, is there anyway I could write a small php script to overwrite the htaccess file with the non infected version every 5-6 minutes to minimize the chances of it affecting my users?

Thanks

UPDATE: It happened again. This time, I cross checked the time at which the new htaccess file was created with the access logs and found one ip that matched closely. According to 2 online IP tracking tools, the IP is situated in  Weehawken, New Jersey, USA. The IP was accessing some of my really old PHP files. As they were no longer in major use, I deleted all of them. Waiting to see if it still continues, and looking at how they accessed the files in the first place to replace them.

Comment: Chances are you've got a rootkit. Changing passwords won't matter, as every password you change is probably forwarded to whoever controls the box, or they have a backdoor installed, which doesn't need a password to access your system. I'd recommend wiping the machine and starting over. Additionally, if you use any of the passwords you've assigned anywhere else, you should change them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've been hacked, you most certainly have a backdoor installed - reinstall all wordpress installations from scratch after changing your password and you should be fine. As for the attacks, I'd recommend to set the htaccess-files to readonly for the time being and set up a monitoring system to alert you on redirects.

If the breaches continue, install a traffic sniffer or check the access logs. I do not mean to be rude, but if you do not know how to handle a security breach, you might be better off letting someone else secure your system for you, before someone puts some really nasty stuff on your servers.

Comment: Re installing the wordpress is exactly what I plan on doing if I do not have this fixed within the hour. I have been managing my sites for 5 years now, and this is the first time one of them has been hacked.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest it - searching for a rootkit will take hours. But it's important to find the security flaw leading to the breach through traffic sniffs and logs first, or you'll be in the same position in a few minutes again.

Comment: I checked everything and finally found it. An extra script had been installed in my servers root. Not /html. It was in /. I replaced it and now everything's peachy.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any foolproof way to prevent this? I know that the thumb.php used in wordpress had a bug to allow people to do this, but my install of wordpress has no theme or plugin with thumb.php in any form.

It depends on how they are doing this. You may want to check that nothing else, especially a remote php filemanager, has been uploaded and whether it's being accessed whenever .htaccess is being rewritten. You can probably find that in your webserver logs. Look for php files that are being accessed (perhaps by a Russian IP?) that don't look like they belong to wordpress or whatever other web application you have set up. The filename could be `wsh.php` or some other benign name like `image.php`. There could be more than one scattered amongst your document root.

Also make sure that your directory permissions aren't writable by any user. This would allow another user on your hosted machine (if you are using shared hosting) to simply copy files into your directories.

> In case there is no solution, is there anyway I could write a small php script to overwrite the htaccess file with the non infected version every 5-6 minutes to minimize the chances of it affecting my users?

If they're diligent enough, they can just delete this script. Or write a script themselves to upload the bad .htaccess every 5 or 6 minutes. You need to find out how they're rewriting your .htaccess file, and how they managed to do this in the first place and prevent it from happening again.